# How do I Retrieve and Display the Internet History Information in Python?

Tags: python, internet-explorer, browser-cache, browser-history

I want to display all the Internet History Information of a system using Python. The index.dat file holds all the history information of user, but it's encoded. How can I decode it?

[I have heard about WinInet Method `INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO`. It provides information about websites visited, hit counts, etc.]

Are there any libraries available in Python for achieving this? If not, are there any alternatives available?

Comment: Which browser are you talking about?

Comment: Please edit your question to specify that you only care about Internet Explorer, or that you'd like to know how for any browser. Not everyone uses Internet Explorer. In fact, the majority of internet users do NOT use Internet Explorer.

Comment: I wanna do this for all browser Browsing Histories... I did this for IE by reading Index file. But i could able to get only the URL from index.dat file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code to get the URL only from index.dat file(History of IE Only)

```
import sys,os
from string import *
from binascii import *
from chardet import *
import re
arr=[]
ar=[]
st=""
url=""
lines=[]

def removenonascii(s):

    l=""
    for i in s:
        if(ord(i)==46 or ord(i)==47 or ord(i)==72 or ord(i) in range(97,97+26) or ord(i) in range(65,65+26)):
        l=l+i
    lines=l.split('\n')


    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith("http"):
            print line.split("URL")[0]

infile =open("C:\Users\Cho\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History\History.IE5\MSHist012012030720120308\index.dat","r")
for line in infile:
    arr=line.split("Cho")

for s in arr:
    removenonascii(s)
    print s
```

Comment: You may want to be aware of the fact that chardet is not included in python. There is nothing wrong with a dependency, but it may be helpful to point this out.

Comment: What do all those imports do? `string` is long obsolete, and I don't see a single call to anything that's not a built-in function or method. `chardet` and `binascii` look pretty irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do this for Firefox history, it's an SQLITE database in the file places.sqlite in the user's firefox profile. It can be opened with python's sqlite3 library. Now if you only care about Explorer (as implied by your mention of index.dat), well I don't know about that.

Comment: I wanna do this for all browser Browsing Histories...  I did this for IE by reading Index file. But i could able to get only the URL from index.dat file.

Comment: Thanks.. Is it differs for every broswer..? Is ther any common place or Register that holds All Browsing Information of system..

Comment: @Chola, there is no central registry of internet history. Every browser can keep track of its history in its own way, and does. If you want to examine Chrome, Opera or Safari history, you'll have to research it separately.